# JDBC Prepared Statements not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql, swing, jdbc

The following jdbc code  giving error `MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;`. Help me to find it.

```
   String selectqry="select * from raildb"+ "WHERE id=?"; 
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(host,uName,uPass);              
   ps1=con.prepareStatement(selectqry);
   ps1.setInt(1,MyModel.idno);        
   ResultSet rs=ps1.executeQuery();
```

Comment: If you had read the error message from the exception, it would have been obvious.

Comment: Dont see why you need to concatenate 2 Strings at all ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a space to your query

```
String selectqry="select * from raildb "+ "WHERE id=?"; 
                                      ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Add space in your sql query between **tablename** and keyword **where**

```
String selectqry="select * from raildb "+ " WHERE id=?";
```